# CakePHP problem with inflections

Tags: cakephp, rules

I have problem with inflections.
I created a model SentSms and a controller for it called SentSmsesController.
It doesn't work properly so I've tried use Inflector::rules

```
Inflector::rules('plural', array(
    'rules' => array('/^(sms)$/i' => '\1es'),
    'irregular' => array('sms' => 'smses')
));

Inflector::rules('singular', array(
    'rules' => array('/^(sms)es$/i' => '\1'),
    'irregular' => array('smses' => 'sms')
));
```

But it did not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with custom inflections, but looks like your rules look for an *exact* match of "sms". Since your model is called "SentSms" it'll never match the custom rules. Try removing the ^ character (start of line) from the regex or use the full name of your model.